# Chromedriver fails to start when using VPN on Windows (selenium, python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting an error when trying to run a python code that opens chromedriver through selenium(Only when using VPN, without VPN it runs fine).
This only happens on Windows, on Mac it works fine.

I run the python command to run the script, then Chrome opens and freezes for about 20 seconds.
Then Chrome closes, and I get this response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 461, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ickoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\ickoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\ickoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\ickoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ickoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.66)
```

The chromedriver is the same version as Chrome, I read everything I could find on the internet, and I didn't find a solution.

This only happens when I am connected to VPN (Cyberghost)

The code I try to run:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension(
    './location2.crx') # this is an extension I have saved locally
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1
})
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

I really need a solution for this, I've read that Firefox works fine, but haven't tested it, since the extension I am using isn't available for Firefox.
Thanks.

Comment: your VPN may be preventing the driver from accessing localhost.  I think you can set the "DebuggerAddress" in ChromeOptions to "127.0.0.1" to avoid this?: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeOptions.htm

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks, I will try that now, though I need to access the website I'm testing through the VPN.